# Changing private variable of object in a vector

Tags: c++, class, return, setter

I am trying to change the value of an int variable in my Card class shown below:

```
class Card {
  public:
    enum Suits {diamond, heart, club, spade};
    Card (int _rank, Suits _suit) : rank{_rank}, suit{_suit} {}
    int getRank();
    void changeRank(int change);

  private:
    int rank;
    Suits suit;
};
```

card.cpp:

```
int Card::getRank() {
  return rank;
}

void Card::changeRank(int change) {
    rank = change;
}
```

Here is the Player class:

```
class Player {
  private:
    vector<Card> playerHand;

  public:
    Card getCard(int index);
};
```

player.cpp:

```
Card Player::getCard(int index) {
    return playerHand[index];
}
```

Here is the dealer.cpp file that actually makes the call:

```
if (oneOrEleven == 11) {
    player.getCard(i).changeRank(11);
    cout << "The ace will have a value of 11" << endl;
}
```

This code is calling the method "changeRank()", it's just not changing the value of "rank" in the Card object.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getCard` is returning by value and so what you get is a copy. Change it to return by reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change `Player::getCard` from return-by-value to return-by-reference. e.g.

```
Card& Player::getCard(int index) {
    return playerHand[index];
}
```

Ohterwise, you'll always modify on the returned copy, which has nothing to do with the original element in the vector.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> This code is calling the method "changeRank()", it's just not changing
>   the value of "rank" in the Card object.

Change the function declaration of getCard to return **by reference**, i.e:

```
Card& getCard(int index);
```

The way you have your function declaration right now, it is returning a Card object **by value**, and not by reference.

When you return by value, you are returning a copy of the object, and not the actual object itself.